# I can not tell the computer when to exit. I am creating a mm model

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api, pyalgotrade

```
Highestprice = ta.highest(close, 20)
LowestPrice = ta.lowest(close, 200)



Bid1exitCondition = state == 1 and close > fairValue and close < Highestprice[1]



if Bid1exitCondition
    strategy.close("Bid 1 Close")
    state:= 0
```

I was expecting an exit. I defined an exit in the bidexit condition. But nothing happened.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your entry should be like this :

```
strategy.entry('long', strategy.long, qty=Q_Jetons, stop=limiteachat, limit=limiteachat)
```

Then your exit should be like this :

```
strategy.exit(id='Exit', from_entry="long", stop=StopLoss)
```

In your exit you need to specify the name of your entry in **from_entry**, here it is 'long'

Comment: from_entry is not an argument for strategy.exit function in version 5 pinescript. 

I think there is a problem in this:-

Bid1exitCondition = state == 1 and close > fairValue and close < Highestprice[1]

Comment: @AnkitThakur : from_entry is an argument for strategy.exit in pinescript V5. You should see the manual page : https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy{dot}exit